# Extjs change formpanel field value before save

Tags: extjs

I try to force a value into a field of a form field. I want to change the field named equipmentcode then save the record.

I can get the form values with getForm().getValues(). Is there a setValues() function ?

I’m really thankful ahead for your help.

Best regards

Comment: You can either use `setValue` on the specific field and call `updateRecord` of the form before saving, or if there is an underlying model you can also set the value directly in the model with `set` method.